# How to use fifo algorithm in android in sending data?

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I'm trying to implement FIFO algorithm in android.
So what I want to happen is that:
Use FIFO algorithm and send those direction one at a time. How to use fifo in this kind of situation. sending those direction direct to other device with time interval. I am using android.

```
//This is a function
    private void sendData(String message) {
            byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();

            Log.d(TAG, "...Send data: " + message + "...");

            try {
                outStream.write(msgBuffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
                if (address.equals("00:00:00:00:00:00")) 
                    msg = msg + ".\n\nUpdate your server address from 00:00:00:00:00:00 to the correct address on line 35 in the java code";
                    msg = msg +  ".\n\nCheck that the SPP UUID: " + MY_UUID.toString() + " exists on server.\n\n";
                    errorExit("Fatal Error", msg);       
                }
            }


//this filter directions
while (!(node.parent == null)) {
            //DIRECTIONS: L - Left, R - Right, U - up, D - Down
            int nextX, nextY;
            String direction = "";
            nextX = node.parent.x;
            nextY = node.parent.y;

            if(nextX == node.x){
                if(nextY > node.y){
                    direction = "S";
                }else{ 
                    direction = "N";
                    sendData("n");
                }

            }
            if(nextY == node.y){
                if(nextX > node.x){
                    direction = "E";
                    sendData("e");
                }
                else{
                    direction = "W";
                    sendData("w");
                }
            }
            if(nextY != node.y){
                if(nextX < node.x){
                    direction = "NW";
                    sendData("7");
                }else{
                    direction = "NE";
                    sendData("6");
                }
            }



            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(direction), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            node = node.parent;
        }
    }
```

Comment: the default for sending data is FIFO btw if only one socket is open

Comment: so i dont need to create any fifo for sending data?